# Difference between static library and relocatable object file?

Tags: linux, linker, static-libraries, elf

What is the difference between static library and relocatable object file? Or between dynamic library and shared object file.

And if it's not equal things, what have dynamic library, that allows to link with it, but shared object file doesn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A static library is basically just a collection of object files. It's typically just an `ar` archive of object files. Using `ar`, you can extract object files from the library, add different object files to it, etc.

Generally speaking, the difference between a dynamic library and a shared object file is the target -- Windows uses dynamic libraries, Linux uses shared objects. There is a little more difference than that, but not a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic (shared) libraries uses [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) code - the code will work regardless of the actual physical location of the library that is used by multiple executables in memory.

Static libraries are linked into the executable during the linking phased to create the executable.

The advantage of dynamic libraries is the smaller footprint of the executable in memory. The advantage of static libraries is that you can just deliver the executable without the need to have the dynamic libraries and run a little faster and no effort is required to enable the library to exist anywhere in physical memory.

Comment: But my questions is about "library vs object file" and not about "static vs dynamic lib". Also my English is not wery well :). So, if it all because of tangled question writing -- tell me, please.

Comment: A library is just a collection of files. Just make sure that collection is for either being shared or static. My answer is to tell you the difference between having the files for being shared or as static.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect in just about every detail ;-(  On a ix86 Linux one can create shared libraries from non-`PIC` code. Static libraries can contain `-PIC` code, and can be linked into shared libraries. The memory footprint of an executable using dynamic linking is *larger* than one that doesn't.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - I think that the right way to say it is that when two or more processes call the same function, then packing this function in a dynamic library saves some total memory space in the system, as the function is loaded just once (hence the "shared object" terminology).

Answer (score 0):

Shard libraries save disk space if they are used by more than one executable.  If multiple executable's that use the same function from a shared lib. are running each will get its own copy. Neither executable on disk will include that function's code but rather a reference to the shared lib.